# How to let C# save a WPF canvas to an image in a PDF document at A1 size?

Tags: c#, pdf

I am in trouble, because I have to save a canvas to an image in a PDF document at A1 size with C#.

I have tried a few examples at the internet, but they do not work for me.

I already have done a little part of this requirement. With this code, I can export it as an image:

```
public static class util { 
    public static void SaveWindow(Window window, int dpi, string filename)
    {
        var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
            (int)window.Width, //width
            (int)window.Width, //height
            dpi, //dpi x
            dpi, //dpi y
            PixelFormats.Pbgra32 // pixelformat
            );
        rtb.Render(window);

        SaveRTBAsPNG(rtb, filename);

    }

    public static void SaveCanvas(Window window, Canvas canvas, int dpi, string filename)
    {
        Size size = new Size(window.Width, window.Height);
        canvas.Measure(size);
        //canvas.Arrange(new Rect(size));

        var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
            (int)window.Width, //width
            (int)window.Height, //height
            dpi, //dpi x
            dpi, //dpi y
            PixelFormats.Pbgra32 // pixelformat
            );
        rtb.Render(canvas);

        SaveRTBAsPNG(rtb, filename);
    }

    private static void SaveRTBAsPNG(RenderTargetBitmap bmp, string filename)
    {
        var enc = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.PngBitmapEncoder();
        enc.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

        using (var stm = System.IO.File.Create(filename))
        {
            enc.Save(stm);
        }
    }
```

Code above saves the canvas as an image.

Comment: Have you just tried installing a PDF printer and printing the canvas?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried until now ?

Comment: I already have done a little part with code above.